# Req.files is undefined with multer

Tags: node.js, mongodb

After I managed to save the image in the uploads folder. Now I can’t save it in the donation database with `mongodb`

```html
folder router

const multer = require('multer')

var Storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, "./public/uploads");
    },
    filename: function(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null,  file.originalname);
    }
});

const upload = multer({
  storage: Storage
  }).fields([{name: "image1Upload", maxCount: 1}, {name: "image2Upload", maxCount: 1}]);
 
 router.post('/ajouter-annonce', upload, AnnonceController.annoncePost
```

```html
folder Controller

const annoncePost = (req, res, next) =>{

 const url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host');
 const {titreBien, description, email, address, Categories, EtatBien } = req.body
 
 const saveAnnonce = new Annonce({
   titreBien,
   description,
   email,
   address,
   Categories,
   EtatBien,
   image2Upload: url + '/public/uploads/' +  req.files['image2Upload'][1]
 })

//   url + '/public/uploads/' + req.file.filename

 console.log(saveAnnonce);
 next()
```

```html
 
   console.log(
{
  _id: 60185a53e2cdee45201b9334,
  titreBien: 'deballage',
  description: 'test',
  email: 'ahmadanote26@gmail.com',
  address: '24 Rue du maréchal juin',
  Categories: 'Habillement',
  EtatBien: 'Etat Neuf',
  image2Upload: 'http://localhost:3000/public/uploads/undefined',
  date: 2021-02-01T19:45:23.356Z
}

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the limit `maxCount: 1` for both files.

```
fields([{name: "image1Upload", maxCount: 1}, {name: "image2Upload", maxCount: 1}]);
```

And here you accessed the file at `image2Upload[1]` which doesn't exist. It should be written as below

```
 const saveAnnonce = new Annonce({
   titreBien,
   description,
   email,
   address,
   Categories,
   EtatBien,
   image2Upload: url + '/public/uploads/' +  req.files['image2Upload'][0].filename //file is present at position 0 as maxCount is only 1
 })
```

Comment: I tried to do that but he gives me result:   console.log( image2Upload: 'http: // localhost: 3000 / public / uploads / [object Object])

Comment: add ```.filename``` after ```req.files['image2upload'][0]```

Comment: Sincerely thank you he walked.
Thanks for your help

Comment: You're welcome. Please upvote if my answer is helpful